# Trying to clear input placeholder on focus/touch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code:

```
<TextInput value={this.state.task} underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} placeholder = {'+ הוסף משימה חדשה'}
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              this.setState({task: text});
            } }
            onEndEditing={()=> this.addTask()}
            />
```

Not sure how I can do this. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**onFocus**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onfocus) method like this

```
<TextInput
  value={this.state.task}
  onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
/>

onFocus() {
  this.setState({
    task: ''
  });
}
```